# How to generate two random numbers out of 4?

Tags: java, android

I need two random numbers out of 1, 2, 3 and 4, but they cannot be the same and I need them in two different variables.

So, something like `rnd1 = 1;` and `rnd2 = 3;`.

I tried to generate them classic style: `int rnd = new Random().nextInt(3) + 1;`. And for the other one the same way, but how to ensure that they don't match? How to do that?

Comment: keep checking the equality of two numbers recursively until u get both different...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than implementing the randomness and unicity yourself, you could simply populate a list with the allowed numbers, [shuffle it](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%3C?%3E%29) and take the first two entries:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
Collections.shuffle(list);
rnd1 = list.get(0);
rnd2 = list.get(1);
```

Comment: Good answer, but this code more expensive because of using generics and Boxing/Unboxing. Anyway, it's not important for small size of list.

Comment: @assylias it depends on volume list data. Creating a lot of objects and garbage collection of them is expensive, as for me.
Sorry, your answer is realy good, maybe i reacted in this way because i'm an android developer, and performance is really important for me sometimes.
I still like your answer, I learned from it something new for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```
Random random = new Random();
int rnd1 = random.nextInt(3) + 1;
int rnd2 = rnd1;
while(rnd2 == rnd1) {
    rnd2 = random.nextInt(3) + 1;
}
```

Comment: You could resuse the same `Random`.

Comment: @AntonM. Good answer and actually you beat me.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the easiest way could be:

```
Random random = new Random();
int rnd1 = random.nextInt(3) + 1;
int rnd2;
do {
    rnd2 = random.nextInt(3) + 1;
} while (rnd1 == rnd2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign the first value to the second then use a while loop until the two values are not equal.

```
int rnd = new Random().nextInt(3) + 1;
int rnd2 = rnd;

while(rnd2 == rnd){
  rnd2 = new Random().nextInt(3) + 1;
}
```

Comment: I was late with my answer to the 12 seconds =(

Comment: Your loop will never execute.

Comment: @AntonM But yours is correct. This while loop is incorrect - it will assign the same int to both variables.